# Japanese and Russian Characters in the same Document

Tags: languages, cjk, cyrillic

I'm writing a document in English.  However, I need to use a few words of both Japanese and Russian.  In principle, it seems to work, but as soon as I used Japanese characters, I cannot use Russian characters afterwards.  Please note that it is crucial for me that the document compiles using pdflatex.

Here are two minimal examples to illustrate my problem.

This one works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
ル
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф}
  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
  ル
  \end{CJK}
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф}
\end{document}
```

I cannot figure out why.  In the second case, I get this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\CJK@XX ...r `#1\endcsname {`#2}\CJK@ignorespaces 
                                                  \fi 
l.12   {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф
                                        }
```

I cannot find any explanation and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suggest XeLaTeX (with `xeCJK`) or LuaLaTeX (with `luatexja-fontspec`).

Answer (score 8):

Hmm seems like CJK package is making some definitions global when perhaps it shouldn't. You can reset the `inputenc` settings like so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф}
  \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
  ル
  \end{CJK}%
\sbox0{\input{utf8.def}}%
  {\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont ф}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pete Welcome to tex.sx! If David’s answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the check below the vote count.

Answer (score 8):

David Carlisle's solution works, but it is not as good as it could be.

In fact, there's a `CJKutf8` package which solves the problem that `inputenc` and `CJK` packages may conflict.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}

ру́сский: абвгдеАБВГДЕ

English: abcdefABCDEF

日本語：ぁぃぅぇぉか

\clearpage\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

### NOTES:

1. Please always use `CJK` environment globally, unless you know what you are doing.
   The extra `\clearpage` is used to solve an old sutle bug of `CJK` described in the package document.
2. `T2A` font encoding is sufficient if you only use basic Latin letters used by English. However, if you need more accented letters, you can mix `T1` and `T2A` font encodings manually.
3. For multilingual documents, I think it is always preferrable to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. For XeLaTeX, use our `xeCJK` package to support automatical font selection and other features. For LuaLaTeX, use `luatexja` bundle to support similar features.