# Is there a way to prioritise fonts in xecjk? (Or how do I create a fallback font for a text)

Tags: fonts, typography, cjk, chinese, vietnamese

I need help prioritizing fonts for a paper writing about a constructed script that uses a font. However I want another font that will do the thing for a specific part of the font. for example i want a font for kanji and a font for Cyrillic to be separate. how do I prioritize the kanji font and then fallback to the Cyrillic font. All help are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193342/47927