# TOC-related error when Japanese and Russian characters are in the same (italian) document

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, russian, japanese, multilingual

(The *(italian)* in the title refers to the fact that, beside the simple example below, I will also need to use accented letters like àèéìòù.)

I know of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118704/japanese-and-russian-characters-in-the-same-document) question, but since it's old, I'm asking to see how things are today.

Here's the [first snippet from here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Russian), with some cyrillic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
 
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
  Это вводный абзац в начале документа.
\end{abstract}
 
\section{Предисловие}
 Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы
 в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно. Для этого Вы должны установить нужный  язык (russian) и необходимую кодировку шрифта (T2A).

\vskip12pt

\textbf{Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно.}

\vskip12pt

\textit{Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно.} 

\section{Математические формулы}
Кириллические символы также могут быть использованы в математическом режиме.

\begin{equation}
  S_\textup{ис} = S_{123}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and here is the [first snippet from here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Japanese), with some Japanese

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK}

\bigskip

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

I can compile each of them individually with `pdflatex foo.tex`.

However, as soon as I try to "fuse" them in a single file, something strange happens. Here's the "fused" version,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK}

\bigskip

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used. And also accents: àèéìòù

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK*}
 
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
  Это вводный абзац в начале документа.
\end{abstract}
 
\section{Предисловие}
 Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы
 в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно. Для этого Вы должны установить нужный  язык (russian) и необходимую кодировку шрифта (T2A).

\vskip12pt

\textbf{Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно.}

\vskip12pt

\textit{Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно.} 

\section{Математические формулы}
Кириллические символы также могут быть использованы в математическом режиме.

\begin{equation}
  S_\textup{ис} = S_{123}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which is "correctly" typeset upon the first run of `pdflatex`, except that following attemps fail, unless I first delete the generated `foo.toc` file, which contains this:

```
\babel@toc {russian}{}\relax 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}これは最初のセクションである}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}これは最初のセクションである}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Предисловие}{1}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}Математические формулы}{1}{}%
```

Comment: I would recommend to use lualatex for documents with more than one script.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, [still no luck](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675038/how-do-i-use-accented-latin-letters-russian-japanese-in-the-same-document).