# Uppercase epsilon-like letter in text mode: what is it and how do I get it?

Tags: symbols, characters, calligraphy

Here it is, circled in red. It looks like a greek epsilon, ε, but it is upper case. To me, it looks like a `\mathcal{E}`, but I'm not sure as it is in text. Furthermore, I don't know if this book was typeset with LaTeX (I think not). But anyway, should I just go for `$\mathcal{E}$ the rest of the text`, or is there a proper way to render it?

[image]

The language is referred to as *a dialect of modern Aramic spoken in Alqosh, a small town in northern Iraq*. The photo is taken from [*The Unfolding of Language*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unfolding-Language-Guy-Deutscher/dp/0099460254/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2XYXWS2W5CF55&keywords=the%20unfolding%20of%20language&qid=1673092234&sprefix=the%20unfolding%20of%20language%20%2Caps%2C80&sr=8-1).

Comment: Umm, the uppercase form of the Greek lowercase letter "epsilon" (and "varepsilon") and the uppercase form of the Latin lowercase letter "e" are identical: "E".

Comment: Since this is a linguistic gloss, probably the symbol means "empty", possibly the author intended a lower case epsilon which was only available in a different font with somewhat bigger letters. Maybe just `$\varepsilon$` would be a good option here.

Comment: @Marijn, "empty"? Are you saying that symbol, by convention, is used mark a missing thing? Would you please provide a source to support this statement?

Comment: It is not used like that by convention, normally you gloss as literally as possible and then in the third line add (English) words that are implied in the original language, so if an equivalent of "that" is not there in the sentence in your screenshot then you would not put in on the second line. However, it might be (I don't know if that is the case, it is just my guess) that the author here has used it like that. It could also be that the symbol is actually a sound in that language and this is some kind of transliteration choice.

Comment: But since you have the original source, maybe you can tell what is the more plausible explanation. So, which language is it, which book or paper did this example come from, is the symbol used in other places in that publication or not? I tried to look it up but all I found was a Pinterest account about grammar so I doubt that is the original source :)

Comment: You might want to consider Ɛ U+0190 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER OPEN E, but how to obtain it depends very much on the engine you use for typesetting: is it LuaLaTeX or pdflatex?

Comment: @Marijn, updated.

Comment: @egreg, pdfLaTeX, but based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674077/toc-related-error-when-japanese-and-russian-characters-are-in-the-same-italian#comment1674771_674077), I think I might move to LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this seems to be a phonetic transcription, it may be the symbol for the [open-mid front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel).

[image]

Several packages have phonetic symbols. The image above uses `\textepsilon` from the `tipa` package, which supports upright and italic shapes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll}
\emph{\textepsilon} & \emph{br\=ata} & \emph{kemxaz-y\=a-le} & \emph{brona}\\
that & girl & saw-\textbf{she-him} & boy
\end{tabular}

`that girl saw the boy'

\end{document}
```

For a slightly larger symbol you could use `\emph{\large\textepsilon}`

[image]

Comment: I have to verify with gimp or something whether it's an optical illusion, but to me it looks like the epsilon is uppercase sized in the original text. Here it is a lower case size.

Comment: @Enlico: You could use `\emph{\large\textepsilon}`