# How do I use accented latin letters + russian + japanese in the same document?

Tags: luatex, alphabet, russian, japanese

I've found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15524/87996) and I also referred to the links I posted in [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674077/toc-related-error-when-japanese-and-russian-characters-are-in-the-same-italian).

What I came up with is the following:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  鮫     & 私が見た & 魚\\
  акула  & видела & рыбу\\
  scùàlò & vìde   & péscè\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which has a relatively ugly rendering of cyrillic (I have no idea how nice the japanese is rendered, though),

[image]

which would be good if I didn't include the `luatexja-fontspec` package, at the expense of not showing japanese characters at all,

[image]

Quite funny, while I write the question, I see the browser has a better clearer idea of the fonts (except that it doesn't render the japanese characters as monospace; but this is not what I'm trying to do):

[image]

Comment: The `babel` package has a commands `\babelfont` and `\foreignlanguage` that let you select a particular font for a particular language. See babel docs, pages 4 and 5. But I do not know how it would work, in your case.

Comment: A quick answer (I can prepare a more extended one tomorrow). Add just after  loading `babel` the following: `\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}` 
`\babelfont[japanese]{rm}{IPAexMincho}`, and delete `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}`. However, I wonder if there is a way to render correctly with the latter the Russian text without the CJK full width spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

luatexja splits characters in two classes. By default cyrillic is handled as a JAchar. You can change that to ALchar:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2}} %range 2 is now ALchar
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} \setsansfont{Noto Sans} \setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  鮫     & 私が見た & 魚\\
  акула  & видела & рыбу\\
  scùàlò & vìde   & péscè\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although Ulrike solved the issue with your MWE, in case you just need Japanese for some words or phrases, here is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{japanese}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[japanese]{rm}{IPAexMincho}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont{tt}{Noto Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  鮫     & 私が見た & 魚\\
  акула  & видела & рыбу\\
  scùàlò & vìde   & péscè\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Edit.** The output is identical to Ulrike’s answer.

Comment: Showing the result  as in the other answer would certainly make it better :D

Comment: It’s identical to Ulrike’s. No need, I think, to post an image that is basically the same. But I’ve edited my answer to point this out.

Comment: Oh, ok, the comment is equivalent, thanks.

Comment: Regarding _in case you just need Japanese for some words or phrases_, as opposed to what? As in, what is this solution not giving that Ulrike's solution does? I'm asking this because yes, I only need a few words, but that's true also for the cyrillic, so maybe your answer would be even different, considering this?

Comment: I get a ``File `japanese.sty' not found.``. Would you please give a hint as to how to install it on Linux via `tlmgr`?

Comment: @Enlico  `japanese.sty` is not required.

Comment: @Enlico So, from your comment I deduce your question is, «I’d like to typeset a document in English, with some words in Russian and Japanese». Right? Japanese has very special typographical requirements, like vertical writing, which are available in frameworks like luatexja. However, for more or less straightforward and simple texts, `babel` should be enough.